# Move elements in a List?

Tags: dart

Consider: `['A', 'B', 'C']`

I'd like to do

```
list.move("B", -1);
list.move("A", 1);
```

resulting in `["B", "C", "A"]`.

Is there some sort of one liner to move items in a listin Dart? Obviously could do this manually in a few lines just curious if there is some easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed no built-in way to do this.

Since the list keeps the same length, the most efficient approach would move the elements in-place rather than remove an element and then insert it again. The latter requires moving all later elements as well, where doing it in-place only requires moving the elements between `from` and `to`.

Example:

```dart
extension MoveElement<T> on List<T> {
  void move(T element, int offset) {
    var from = indexOf(element);
    if (from < 0) return; // Or throw, whatever you want.
    var to = from + offset;
    // Check to position is valid. Or cap it at 0/length - 1.
    RangeError.checkValidIndex(to, this, "target position", length);
    element = this[from];
    if (from < to) {
      this.setRange(from, to, this, from + 1);
    } else {
      this.setRange(to + 1, from + 1, this, to);
    }
    this[to] = element;
  }
}
```

I would probably prefer a more general "move" function like:

```dart
extension MoveElement<T> on List<T> {
  void move(int from, int to) {
    RangeError.checkValidIndex(from, this, "from", length);
    RangeError.checkValidIndex(to, this, "to", length);
    var element = this[from];
    if (from < to) {
      this.setRange(from, to, this, from + 1);
    } else {
      this.setRange(to + 1, from + 1, this, to);
    }
    this[to] = element;
  }
}
```

and then build the "find element, then move it relative to where it was" on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

linear? I don't think there is any. In any case, a sample code here:

```
extension on List<String> {
  void move(String element, int shift) {
    if (contains(element)) {
      final curPos = indexOf(element);
      final newPos = curPos + shift;

      if (newPos >= 0 && newPos < length) {
        removeAt(curPos);
        insert(newPos, element);
      }
    }
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  print(list);
  list.move('B', 2);
  print(list);
  list.move('B', -3);
  print(list);
}
```

Result:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F]
[A, C, D, B, E, F]
[B, A, C, D, E, F]
```

Comment: Marking as correct as I think this correctly answers that no, there is no shortcut way to do this. Thx for the snippet!